# Internal compiler error : segmentation fault with g++4.3.5

Tags: c++, g++

Here is the code

```
   //fail_.cpp
   template< unsigned char X, class L>
   class A {
      public:
      typedef void (A::*fptr)();
      class B {   
           public: B(typename A< X, L> ::fptr );
      };
   };
   template < unsigned char X, typename L >
   A<X,L>::B::B ( fptr ) { }
```

`g++ -c fail_.cpp` gives

> fail_.cpp:11: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault 
>   Please submit a full bug report,
>   with preprocessed source if appropriate.
>   See < file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.3/README.Bugs > for instructions.

Looks like a bug to me in g++4.3.5, g++4.4 and higher don't give any such segfault.

What do you guys think? Is there something wrong with the code itself?

Comment: An internal compiler error is always a bug. If there's something wrong with the code the compiler should produce an actual error message, not crash.

Comment: Looks ok to me. I would probably have tried to simplify the inner class to `class B { public: B(fptr); };`. The typedef should be visible there.

Comment: Interestingly, if I write `typename A< X, L> ::fptr` in the *definition*, it compiles fine : http://ideone.com/0OOpn

Comment: in c++11 you dont need the `typename` there. try whether that prevents the bug.

Comment: @Prasoon: I get the same internal error with g++ 4.3.2, seems like it could affect the whole 4.3 branch.

Comment: If it doesn't happen every time, it might be a HW problem

Comment: @VJovic: It happens everytime.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb : Without typename the code compiles without any segfault.

Answer (score 2):

I see a similar failure with gcc 4.2.  As others have said, an internal error means something went badly wrong inside the compiler, which does **not** imply that it's your code that was bad.

It works fine in g++ 4.6 and clang 3.0.

Answer (score -1):

typename should be used as a replacement for class in the template section.

In inner class B, passing the function pointer does not require the keyword typename, because A< X,L> is already known to the compiler at that point.

And maybe giving the typename in front of the type is causing the compiler to malform (may be undefined behavior?).