# How to debug g++: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, segmentation-fault, g++

I've implemented [this LRU cache sample](https://gist.github.com/christian-comp-techniques/e5eff09a8566ad2556f640d643226576) from HackerRank. It includes 500,000 test cases for the cache in the main function. When I try to compile it with

```
g++ -Wall -std=c++17 cache.cpp -o cache
```

it fails with this message:

```
g++: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault signal terminated program cc1plus
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-9/README.Bugs> for instructions.
```

Memory usage during compilation was decent, far away from any limits. My g++ version is

```
me@vie:$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-11ubuntu0~18.04.1) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

How do do I find out more what exactly is causing the compiler to fail? I've seen [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9818751/internal-compiler-error-segmentation-fault-with-g4-3-5) and comments saying this is a bug but before I submit an issue I'd like to doublecheck if this isn't just some bad design on my end.

Comment: If the compiler segfaults, there is definitely a bug in the compiler. It shouldn't do that regardless of what you throw at it.

Comment: I've replaced the link so the code is not truncated. The test cases are generated by HackerRank, I've just added them directly to main and output the results on stdout.

Comment: And, if I just use <100,000 test cases, no errors are thrown.